# HttpContext.Current.User.Identity suddenly stopped working in visual studio 2017

Tags: asp.net

I am using HttpContext.Current.User.Identity in my asp.net web application. Visual studio version is 2017.
This piece of code suddenly stopped working & throwing null value.
Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Was there any logout? or timeout due to idle?

Comment: can you post the code where it is throwing null exception error?

Comment: Could possible be a result of session settings being amended in IIS?

Comment: I'm using this line to fetch the ID of currently logged in user : String ID =  HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.ToString();  & found that null value is coming in ID during debugging. There was no logout or timeout.

Comment: The application is working fine in server. I'm facing this issue only in local machine.